# What's the correct way to compare a typed object's field to a primitive in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, tslint

If you have a typed object's field and wish to compare it to a primitive, say to `1` or `ABCD`, what is the correct way to do that?

Here's an example.

```
interface Model {
  __typename: "floors";
  value: number;
  formattedValue?: string;
}
```

This comparison gives me the answer I'm looking for, but tslint says `== should be ===`.

```
if (model.value == 1) {
     return true;
}
```

This does not give me the answer I'm looking for. It does not return true, even though `value` is 1.

```
if (model.value === 1) {
     return true;
}
```

How can I do this comparison without offending tslint?

The only way I found was to do this was:

```
if (Number(value) === 1) {
     return true;
}
```

... but creating a Number just to do a comparison feels wrong.

Comment: you should really debug your code. I have the feeling that at runtime value is actually a string not a number. :)

Comment: But the field is specified as `number`, do they just get switched willy-nilly at runtime? O_O

Comment: TypeScript types are ultimately only assertions. If the value comes from an external or non-type-checked source, you still have to verify that it's actually the type it says it is, or make sure to convert it before assigning it.

Comment: Type hints are just that, *hints*. They don't enforce the type at run time. Depending on how the rest of your code generates an instance of `Model`, it could very well be something other than a `number`.

Comment: To be more specific, if the object implementing `Model` comes from a result of operation declared to return `any`, for example `JSON.parse()`, then it could be `any`thing.

Comment: What toskv said. The best way to do it is indeed with the === operator (== is considered bad practice). And if at runtime, the value is *indeed* a number, there's no reason for that not to work. If it's a string, on the other hand (which seems to be the case), then the problem is when the field is assigned a value

Comment: thanks to everyone for taking over :) In the end everything in typescript gets compiled into javascript, the type checks are only at build time to make sure your code doesn't do anything that it should. At runtime all bets are off and you're still in javascript land. You should check the value you get at runtime and adjust your typing accordingly. Because if you have a server sending you a string and you treat it as a value your typing of it is wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, tell TSLint to stop checking for `==`: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/

```
// tslint.json
{
    "rules": {
        "triple-equals": false
    }
}
```

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/triple-equals/

The comments on the original post are spot on. Although you've declared in TypeScript that the `value` properties are always `number`s, it seems wherever you're taking them from is passing them as `string`s. One of the following must be true:

- What you've declared as the typings are incorrect; you should instead say `value: string`
- What you've declared as the typings should be correct, but something is erroneously giving you a `string`

TypeScript is just a collection of development-time hints. It has no bearing on what happens at runtime.